# кнопка ActionBar боковое мену

Tags: android

Есть кнопка которая открывает боковое мену с лева на право - она находится в левом углу в управлении приложением при помощи [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)
Вопрос: как мне перенести эту кнопку в право.чтобы мену открывалось с права на лева